# Back button from "default share intent" exits application - Android

Tags: back-stack

i start a share intent from a drawer menu as below:

```
Intent iFriends = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
             iFriends.setType("text/plain");
             iFriends.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "http://www.liveplus.mobi");
             iFriends.createChooser(iFriends, "Invite Friends");
             startActivity(iFriends);
```

This drawer is on the MainActivity of the application.

when i press the back button, the application exits.
i want it to return to the MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using `android:noHistory="true"` in your Manifest / MainActivity definitions. Remove it and back button will work properly.